# JavaScript Stop Executing after the content changes - Laravel Livewire

Tags: javascript, laravel, swiper.js, laravel-livewire

I have a javascript code to make a slider, and inside the slider, there are content changes when calling a method via livewire, and the problem is when calling it, the slider blows up, and the javascript code won't work.

view:

```html
@foreach($section->children()->get() as $subSection)
  <button wire:click="serviceChanger({{ $subSection->id }})">{{ $subSection->name }}</button>
@endforeach

@foreach($services as $service)
the services here changes depending on the serviceChanger method
@endforeach
```

javascript

```js
  <script>
        var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                slidesPerView: 1,
                spaceBetween: 10,
                // init: false,
                pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination',
                clickable: true,
                },
                breakpoints: {
                640: {
                    slidesPerView: 1,
                    spaceBetween: 20,
                },
                768: {
                    slidesPerView: 2,
                    spaceBetween: 40,
                },
                1024: {
                    slidesPerView: 4,
                    spaceBetween: 50,
                },
                }
        })
  </script>
```

component:

```php
public function serviceChanger($id)
{
  // some logic
}
```

after I call the ServiceChanger, the javascript won't work when the services change.
Any Ideas?

Comment: There's not enough information here to help solve the issue, you've removed essential parts of the code. You should also include relevant error messages in your console, and describe what happens ("blows up" isn't very descriptive).

Comment: thank you for your response, But the question is clear for me. By the way, I am not a native speaker, as I am trying my best to make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve my problem by Dispatching a Browser Event at the end of the `serviceChanger` method

```php
$this->dispatchBrowserEvent('contentChanged');
```

in the JavaScript, file Catch the event like that

```js
window.addEventListener('contentChanged', event => {
        // your JS code
});
```

- You need to re-initialize your javaScript code when Livewire refreshes the content.
- When livewire replaces the HTML in the DOM with your new HTML, none of the JS code executes
- You have to manually make sure everything executes again

For More Info take a look at [Livewire Event](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#browser)